# Проблема с импортом PyQt 5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcreator

```
import PyQt5 import uic
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

делаю все по видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90xZtB3bbcg, но дальше не могу продвигаться, ибо никак не разберусь как это исправить. Я новичок в программировании, надеюсь на поддержку, спасибо

вот код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic


import os

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()
        self.ui.show()

    def start(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('calc.ui')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Выложите Ваш код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Замените `import PyQt5 import uic`   на `from PyQt5 import uic`

Comment: @AlTheOne тут видна ошибка в импорте, плюс он описал ошибку в вопросе

Comment: @Squidward спасибо за правку вопроса.

Comment: `from PyQt5 import uic`

все равно не работает, такое же подчеркивание слова uic (волнистой чертой)

Comment: @Lcashe Лучше код текстом выкладывать. И с картинками меньше возни, в мобилке более читаемое и код индексируется в поисковике.

Comment: я искал решение проблемы в интернете, но так и не понял как именно ее решить, проблема как я понял в пути каких то файлов, или , calc.ui (в моем случае), нужно конвертировать на calc.py

Comment: @Lcashe, хорошо

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7Hi3Efl4_0 делая все по ролику я решил данную проблему

Comment: это хорошо что вы нашли проблему, однако на будущее: если вам помогли с первоначальным вопросом у вас есть еще проблема, задайте отдельный вопрос. у вас изначально тут была проблема с импортом из ```pyqt``` а после у вас появилась проблема с директорией, это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: хорошо, буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Просмотрите видео еще раз. Там написано

```
from PyQt5 import uic
```

Comment: если по отдельности, то 
import PyQt5     работает,а
import uic (слово uic подчеркивается красной волнистой чертой)

Comment: все верно. Вы либо импортируете библиотеку PyQt5 , либо же Вы должны импортировать ИЗ библиотеки при помощи from ... import

Comment: если мой ответ является решением, нажмите на галочку, пожалуйста

Comment: конечно нажму, только я ее еще не решил (

Comment: у вас появилась другая ошибка? или все та же?

Comment: та, которая на скриншоте

Comment: я пока посмотрю по другим урокам работу с PtQt5, думаю это поможет

Comment: проверьте что бы файл calc.py и calc.ui находились в одной и той же папке

Comment: не пойму почему иконка файла calc.ui просто белого цвета, а не иконка QtDesigner, в терминале еще почему то не получается конвертировать calc.ui в calc.py, командой `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x untitled.ui -o untitled.py`, смотрю ролик https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw6q-eBm630

при конвертации, вылазит ошибка `No such file or directory: "calc.ui" ` , не пойму в чем дело, calc.py и calc.ui в одной папке, также еще делал по видео, все равно не получается

Comment: ```pyuic5 -x calc.ui -o calc.py```

Comment: как в видео еще не получается заходить в папки, т.е., я ввожу `cd proj`, но он его не открывает и пишет "Системе не удается найти указанный путь."

Comment: потому что вы не вписываете путь. ```cd``` - ```change directory```

Comment: так я его ввожу

Comment: нет. путь при использовании cd начинается с D:\ или C:\

Comment: у меня почему то cmd открывается сразу в C:\Users\user\  
я пишу dir, он мне показывает все папки этой папки, но в другую папку я почему то зайти не могу все равно, ща пока буду с этим разбираться

Comment: @Squidward  `calc.ui` и `calc.py` в одной папки. А терминал у вас в той же директории что и эти файлы? 
@Lcashe При использовании cd путь не всегда должен начинаться с имени диска. При переходе в поддиректорию это потеря времени.

Comment: @Squidward приймите мой ответ как решение, поскольку на вопрос о проблеме импорта я вам ответил, и это является решением проблемы. Проблема с директориями должна быть задана как новый вопрос.

Comment: @Lcashe , нет проблем

Comment: `Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.`

Надеюсь вам все таки повысят репутацию

Comment: Понял, благодарю все равно) Удачи вам

Answer (score 0):

Так у Вас не с импортом проблема. На скриншоте же написано, что ошибка в отсутствии файла calc.ui, а не в импорте uic. Скорее всего, вы просто забыли поместить файл calc.ui в папку с calc.py

На подсветку импорта красным не обращайте внимания, в PyCharm такое бывает

Comment: он изменил вопрос. по началу была проблема что он написал ```import PyQt5 import uic```, то  решили, теперь эта проблема

Comment: я запарился, завтра попробую сделать, а тут лайки нельзя ставить? Вы помогаете, я хочу вас поблагодарить, а это можно сделать только когда найдется ответ

Comment: около комментария есть стрелочка вверх, можете на нее нажать

Answer (score 0):

Для начала в вашем коде сделайте пути относительно скрипта это снимет часть проблем с отслеживанием что где лежит.

```py
from pathlib import Path 
cur_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
print("Директория скрипта", cur_dir)
# ... Ваш код ...
def start(self):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(cur_dir / 'calc.ui')
```

Далее в консоли проверьте чтобы путь запуска был = пути скрипта. Текст перед тем где вы набираете команду. В принципе все должно работать. Еще если вы преобразуете `calc.ui` -> `calc.py` то это надо отразить и в коде.

Скорее всего Вы просто запутались с путями в системе, а также возможно с тем какой питон использует скрипт системный или виртуальное окружение.

Comment: не понял про директорию скрипта, какого скрипта? и как его стоит вписать?

Comment: "Далее в консоли проверьте чтобы путь запуска был = пути скрипта. Текст перед тем где вы набираете команду. В принципе все должно работать. Еще если вы преобразуете calc.ui -> calc.py то это надо отразить и в коде."
как это все сделать?

Comment: у меня постоянно вылазит вот эта ошибка `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'calc.ui'`

не пойму, всмысле нет такого каталога или файла?

Comment: Да система не видит файл. Тот код что я привел будет подгружать файл 'calc.ui'  если он находится в одной директории со скриптом.  Про консоль вам надо в ней перейти в директорию со скриптом.